# How do I install a redis server on the D drive?

Tags: database, redis

I'm following the instructions at this page here: https://github.com/ServiceStack/redis-windows

I moved the files to a folder on my D Drive but the install won't go through and I get an unknown error. Is it not possible to install the redis server on a drive other than the C drive? If so then how would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default Redis places its heap memory mapped file in the local application folder (e.g.
"%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local"). You can overwrite this location by settings the heapdir in redis.windows.conf, located in the same directory as redis-server.exe. Don't forget to create the folder yourself, Redis won't do it for you.

Now if you start redis server supplying the conf file as the first parameter, this new dir will be used.

You might also need to set the maxheap size (I am using 2GB).

Comment: and use this # maxheap <bytes>
maxheap 1024000000

---- and run like this ---
D:\redis-2.8.17>redis-server.exe redis.windows.conf